# ExtJS Fieldset Collapse issue

Tags: extjs

I have designed Fieldset and checkboxtoggled set to true,My requirement is click on check box(uncheck) of fieldset, Hide some controls in fieldset, again check on checkbox show all controls (need not to collapse fieldset when click on checkbox).

What is the right way to handle this?

(I am using collapse/expand listeners for fieldset, but unable to achieve it)

Comment: You should include the code you have written so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `beforecollapse` & `beforeexpand` event to override the default behavior. Here is what you can do:

```
 listeners: {
    'beforecollapse' :  function(panel,ani) {
        // Hide all the form fields you need to hide 
        return false; // this will avoid collapse of the field set
    },
    'beforeexpand' : function(panel,ani) {
        // Display all the fields
        return false; // this will avoid the default expand behaviour
    }   
 }
```